# Getting error when I run my test using mocha

Tags: javascript, appium, mobile-automation, mocha

I have written a code where it will launch the app, click on the login button, enter username and password and click on sign in.

When I run this using `node 'filename'` it is running fine with no issue.

When I run using mocha  `node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha 'filename'` I am getting the error I am not able to understand as to why?

This is the error that I am getting:

```
2019-01-02T06:52:42.721Z DEBUG wdio-config: wdio-sync not found, running tests asynchronous

/home/user/newtest/node_modules/webdriverio/src/utils.js:199
    (typeof caps['appium-version'] !== 'undefined') ||
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'appium-version' of undefined
at mobileDetector (/home/user/newtest/node_modules/webdriverio/src/utils.js:199:21)
at Object.remote (/home/user/newtest/node_modules/webdriverio/src/index.js:35:29)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/newtest/test13.js:16:21)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:659:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at /home/user/newtest/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:250:27
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/user/newtest/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:247:14)
at Mocha.run (/home/user/newtest/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:576:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/newtest/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:637:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:12)
at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)
at startExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:276:5)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:227:5)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: update WDIO test to v5

Comment: i did still i am facing same issue @Rao

Answer (score 0):

First of all see [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

You're using Strict equality operator with undefined. Strict equality check for both the type and value to be equal.

typeof returns string.

Thus,

```
typeof chartTheme === 'undefined'

returns true.
```

In other words,

```
undefined !== 'undefined'
```

but,

```
undefined == 'undefined'.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of breaking changes in v5 that doesn't allow a seamless upgrade,if you want update WDIO test to v5, you can see [docs](https://webdriver.io/blog/#how-to-upgrade-to-v5)

you can also use v4 to reslove this problem.

some details you can see [issues](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/3186)